# Specifying the default ordering for a has_many association using a join (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

I have a simple Customer model with a has many relationship with a Purchase model.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
end
```

I am repeatedly finding that I need to order Customer.purchases in my views in the following way:

```
@customer.purchases.joins(:shop).order("shops.position").order(:position) #yes, two orders chained
```

In the interest of keeping things DRY, I'd like to put this somewhere centralized so I don't have to repeatedly do it. Ideally, I'd like to make it the default ordering for Customer.purchases. For example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, :order => joins(:shop).order("shops.position").order(:position)
end
```

Obviously the above doesn't work. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your customer model you specified **joins(:shop)** is the value for the key **:order**. I think here is the problem, So you can use the **joins** as a key instead of order like below,

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases, :joins => [:shop], :order => "shops.position"
end
```

I think it may work.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Gives me an `undefined method \`key?' for nil:NilClass` error.

Answer (score 0):

In your purchases model, you can create a class method:

Purchase.rb:

```
def self.order_by_position
  joins(:shop).order("shops.position").order(:position)
end
```

Then you can say things like:

```
@customer.purchases.order_by_position
Purchase.order_by_position
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method on `Customer` that returns ordered purchases:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases

  def ordered_purchases
    purchases.joins(:shop).order("shops.position").order(:position)
  end
end
```

and call `@customer.ordered_purchases` from your views.